# How to properly configure json data to load into a Highstock multiple line graph

Tags: json, highcharts

### Looking for the correct json formating for a Highstock multiple line graph:

Highstock is a great graphing api with lots of documentation. I just can't seem to find out how to format the json file. This is the graph that I am trying to set up:

> http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

This is the api document that discusses how to load data through json:

> http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file
>
> ^--- Only problem here is that the json data example is set up for -Highcharts- not Highstock.

My json data follows this format. There should be six lines of data on the graph if it loads properly:

```
[timestamp, lineA, lineB, lineC, lineE, lineF]

Example:
[1366009207,-46.11,-19.71,-36.94,-20.21,-20.88,8.84]
[1366009217,-31.38,-21.74,-27.27,-24.64,-22.66,8.77] 
 etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! Here is an example of their json data.

> http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=?

**The key: Each graph-line must be loaded as a seperate json file.**